# Stats for documentation proposed changes

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals, badge-request

Great - a new review queue for documentation's proposed changes was turned on last night. So, we can reduce input box noise now.

[image]

I know it's BETA and this question isn't for a problem but a feature request. Maybe other users want this too and I added a snap here to explain.

So, what's about a `stats` tab as like present for first post reviews e.g. for overall stats and for badges of approving?

Comment: They are probably going to monitor it for a while before they throw more dev resources at it.  Hard to imagine it is going to be successful, there has to be a point at which SO users get exhausted from yet more of this go-to solution to a half-baked idea.  Our free time has no value to SE since it doesn't cost them anything, devs are not free.